# Python import failed due to missing symbol

Tags: python, shared-libraries, pybind11

I have an external library with a header file and a .so library. I wanted to wrap this via PyBind11 to access the C code from Python. I can build the module just fine, but when I want to import it, I get:

```
/home/user/dev/external/Python/PyBind_Module/external_python.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: <FUNCTION>
  File "/home/user/dev/external/Python/pybind_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import external_wrapper as exw
ImportError: /home/user/dev/external/Python/PyBind_Module/external_python.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: <FUNCTION>
```

When I do a `nm -gD libexternal.so`, I find  in the exposed list

```
nm -gD /usr/lib/libexternal.so | grep 'FUNCTION'
00000000000170c0 T FUNCTION
0000000000018ff0 T FUNCTIONd
```

I put the file at /usr/lib, which I thought would mean the code should find it when loading .so files, but I now assume I need to tell either the PyBind or my python code to look for that library. How would I fix this?

Edit:

Setup.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

from pybind11.setup_helpers import build_ext
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
from setuptools import setup

example_module = Pybind11Extension(
    "external_python",
    sources=[str(fname) for fname in Path("src").glob("*.cpp")],
    include_dirs=["include", "."],
    extra_compile_args=["-O3"],
    libraries=["/usr/lib/libexternal.so"],
    library_dirs=["/usr/lib"]
)

setup(
    name="external_module",
    version=1.0,
    description="C++ wrapper around the external library",
    ext_modules=[example_module],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues I can think of

1. It could be because you use C code. I don't precisely recall the difference but because of polymorphism, C++ has a different way than C to give names to compiled functions at the ABI level. As the awesome Pybind uses C++ structure, you probably have to use `#ifdef __cpluplus ... extern "C"` like -->

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

... declaration of your C functions

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

2. Maybe your `setup.py` file doesn't include everything, I've made a compilation of a few basic example in [this repo](https://github.com/cjaques/pybind_examples) with various ways to compile a wrapper, this could help.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That did not help though, I still get my missing function. I've adapted your example3 setup.py, and added to compiler options the flags -lexternal, but the built .so file still does complain about undefined symbol.

Comment: Hum, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by maybe trying to single out the `FUNCTION` C function to use in Python?

Comment: https://github.com/SinisterMJ/PyBindTest

This is a minimal as I could get it

Comment: I could get your MRE to work, I just had to also include the C-code file in the `setup.py` file (line 28 of your setup.py becomes `sources=["src/addlib_interface.cpp", "library.c"],`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the .c file accessible. But a coworker pointed me to another SO question, and that worked. I had to create a make file, and cannot use pip install, but I get a .so that properly links to the existing library (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525592/undefined-symbol-error-when-linking-pybind11-with-a-dynamic-library-that-calls-a/69571412#69571412)

Comment: I see, but the SO answer you point to makes a lot of sense, "if it works it's not stupid"!